# Trouble Installing Nginx and php5-fpm on Debian 7.3

Tags: php, nginx, debian

I have a Debian 7.3 installation in a VM that I am practising installing Nginx and php5-fpm on. I got the Nginx working, by assigning it a manual port of `:8080` and that points to `/var/www/` for data and in that directory is an `index.html` and `info.php` file.

The config file for my Nginx is located at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` and looks like this:

```
server {
    listen   8080;

    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /doc/ {
            alias /usr/share/doc/;
            autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow ::1;
            deny all;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

I have tried changing `fastcgi_pass` both ways:

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

and also as:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

In my `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` file I have the following configuration:

```
[www]

user = www-data
 group = www-data

 listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
 ;listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

Here too, I have uncommented the line to match in the Nginx default.conf file.

In my `php.ini` file I have edited it so that it shows `cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0` as required by most of the guides I have seen.

When I try to load nginx, it runs OK. When I try to run php5-fpm this is what happens:

```
root@debianx86:/# /etc/init.d/php5-fpm status
[FAIL] php5-fpm is not running ... failed!

root@debianx86:/# /etc/init.d/php5-fpm reload
[ ok ] Reloading PHP5 FastCGI Process Manager: php5-fpm.

root@debianx86:/# /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
[FAIL] Restarting PHP5 FastCGI Process Manager: php5-fpm failed!

root@debianx86:/# /etc/init.d/php5-fpm start
root@debianx86:/# /etc/init.d/php5-fpm status

[FAIL] php5-fpm is not running ... failed!
root@debianx86:/#
```

I then open up any of the browsers on my VM and point them to either `127.0.0.1:8080` or `localhost:8080` and I get the custom `index.html` loading that I made and it works! So I then try to load the`info.php` file and I get presented with a `404 Not Found - nginx/1.4.4`.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Is there something I'm missing from all this?

I installed nginx from `sudo apt-get -y install nginx` and `sudo apt-get -y install php5-fpm` too. Any dependencies they required would have been installed along with that.

Is there a script that I can run on a fresh install of Debian 7.3 that someone has got that will install it properly for me, and make all the modifications so that nginx and php5-fpm are up and running? I've looked over many of the websites with the instructions and I seem to be doing pretty much everything they do, except for the `default-sites` and `enabled-sites`, as neither of those folders exist for me, and I don't want to run my virtual hosts like that. I will run them with their own servers listed in the default.conf file.

**EDIT:** I have even tried following this article at [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-debian-7) and it still doesn't work.

**EDIT #2:** I also did `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` to ensure that the user and group match the information in the `www.conf` file. I also tried by changing it back to the original `root:root` specs too. Still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I  think maybe port 9000 is already being used, so php5-fpm can't bind with that port and fails to start.

in the fpm pool settings swap the line of port 9000 with the line with the sock file, then try to start php5-fpm like you were doing, if it works then all you need is to update the nginx configuratuin to proxy pass to the sock file instead of the port.

Comment: I've already tried it both ways and still doesn't work. I tested port 9000 to see if anything was on it - nothing. :-(

Comment: what does `sudo service php5-fpm status` say ?, did you try running it after starting with both configurations ?

Comment: I gave me the same results. What I found was that if I installed mySQL first, then Nginx, then php5-fpm it just magically worked the 4th time around?

I thought it was weird, so I purged mySQL and it still worked? So confused.

Comment: I'm going to write a fully-installable script for this. I saw something on [LowEndBox](http://lowendbox.com) that automatically installed LEMP on Debian 6. I'm going to upgrade it for Debian 7 and put it on Github so this doesn't come up again.